# Subview width not fitting superview with autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am adding a subview to a UICollectionViewCell. I am programmatically adding constraints to make it fill the cell, however the width does not fill the cell.

When I view it in the view debugger, it says the position is ambiguous. How  can this be since I am specifying all 4 sides are pinned to the superview?

This is what the views look like in the debugger. The inner, white view should fit the parents width (blue border):

[image]

Inspecting the constraints on the parent view shows this with the "position ambiguous" warning:

[image]

The code I am using is as follows:

```
[self.contentView addSubview:calloutView];
calloutView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[calloutView]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(calloutView) ]];
[self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[calloutView]-0-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(calloutView) ]];
```

Comment: Where are you using this code?

Comment: UICollectionViewDelegate creates a cell and then calls cell setup method which contains this code

Comment: but this code is inside your cell or in your viewController?

Comment: This code is inside a setup method inside the cell

Comment: I will try to reproduce your problem

Comment: In your vertical constraint you are putting option as `NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing`. Is this correct? I have never used options parameter ins visual format so i'm not sure but shouldn't it be top to bottom or something?

Comment: There is no such option. Also I tried it first without using the visual format and got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the use of contentView, you must use the cell itself to achieve what you want, this is the code and works, check the picture below

```
#import "CollectionViewCell.h"

@interface CollectionViewCell()
@property UIView * testView;
@end


@implementation CollectionViewCell

@synthesize testView;

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    testView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    [self addSubview:testView];

    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-2-[testView]-2-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(testView) ]];
    [self addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-2-[testView]-2-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(testView) ]];

    self.testView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    self.testView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
}

@end
```

[image]

I hope this helps you, best regards

Comment: Thanks for that. Did you reproduce the problem when using the contentView? I have just removed it and see no change :(

Comment: @zorro2b I post the answer for your problem, yes I reproduce your problem, and the solution is this, use the cell itself instead of contentView for add your code-created view and setup your constraints there as my code shows, it works!, best regards

Comment: @zorro2b did my answer finally helps you?

Comment: thanks very much, I have it working now. My mistake was that I had set the translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to NO on the cell as well as the subview. Once I removed this to match your example it all worked!